# special characters not getting loaded in oracle 11g DB using sqlldr

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am trying to load a file using sql loader in oracle DB which has special characters as follows:

```
5200504,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,0.25,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,    5200959,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,0.15,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
5201122,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,-0.42,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
5203421,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,-0.05,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
```

As per my analysis I have already checked source file encoding which is `UTF8`. NLS_LANG on Linux machine is `American_america.UTF8`

and oracle DB setting is as follows:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

after load the special character `ÃresutjÃ¤mning` is getting changed to `Öresutjämning`.
the load.ctl file is as follows:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile *
 into table SE_TDC_1_BILL_ITEM
TRUNCATE
 fields terminated by ","
(BILL_NUMBER,SUBSCRIBER_ID,USAGE_DATE_TIME,USAGE_TYPE,CALLING_NUMBER,CALLED_NUMBER,METRIC,VOLUME_,DURATION_,CHARGE_OPCO_C,SOURCE_COUNTRY,TARGET_COUNTRY,SOURCE_NETWORK,TARGET_NETWORK,CHARGEALE,PCTG_CHARGED,PRODUCT,ROAM_TYPE,MT_MO_INDICATOR,TARIFF_TYPE,CONTRACT_ID,CHARGE_CURRENCY,ITEM_TAX_CODE,ITEM_TAX_RATE,SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
BEGINDATA
5200504,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,0.25,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
5200959,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,0.15,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
5201122,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,-0.42,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
5203421,07ED,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,Occurrences,,,-0.05,,,,,TRUE,100,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,,ÃresutjÃ¤mning,,SEK,,0.00,,,
```

Please assist.

Comment: Are you sure about your input string `ÃresutjÃ¤mning` seems to be quite useless, however `Öresutjämning` can be swedish and meas "rounding off the price". For me it looks like Oracle does exactly what it should do, i.e. make a proper translation.

Comment: You can double check by selecting dump() of inserted value . It should be single byte string as in SQL*Loader file.